# Unity C# - Array index out of range

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with unity and here is the code

**The error message:**

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
Sequence.fillSequenceArray () (at Assets/Scripts/Sequence.cs:43)
Sequence.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Sequence.cs:23)
```

**Code:**

```
public int[] colorSequence = new int[100];
public int level = 2;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent("Animator") as Animator;
    fillSequenceArray ();
    showArray (); // just to know

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void showArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < colorSequence.Length; i++) {
        Debug.Log ("Position " + i + ":" + colorSequence[i]);
            }
}

 public void fillSequenceArray(){
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        int numRandom = Random.Range (0, 3);    

        if (colorSequence[i] == 0) {
            colorSequence[i] = numRandom;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the last `if` to `if (!colorSequence[i].Equals(null))`, or 
`if (colorSequence[i] == null)` and the same error occurs. Even if I delete this `if`, the error occurs when I try to fill `colorSequence[i] = numRandom;`

Comment: Where is `colorSequence` initialized?

Comment: sorry, edited public int[] colorSequence = new int[100];

Comment: Is is possible that you modified the 'colorSequence' variable in the editor?  Values in the changed in the editor will override the ones initialized in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check whether the the array contains a value at that index before attempting to access it. Doing otherwise will throw an error instead of returning null.

You can easily check it using the array's length property:

```
    if (colorSequence.Length > i) {
        colorSequence[i] = numRandom;
    }
```

Comment: colorSequence.Length will return the size of array right ? The array was instantiated like this public int[] colorSequence = new int[100]; So will return 100 ?

Comment: I'm not getting why this is happening, I used to do this in java and all works .. I'm really in trouble with c#

Comment: So, I just want to know if the position of array is empty and fill the empty position with the random number

Answer (score 0):

Unlike many languages, C# does not automatically fill an array "slot" outside of its bounds with `null` when you try to access it. When you first declare the array, you must explicitly state its length, and any attempt to *read or write* outside those bounds will generate an error.

```
var colorSequence = new int[length];
```

If you want a list that can dynamically grow or shrink as you add or remove items, you probably want `List<T>` instead.